# Can ~ほうがいいですか be used to ask for recommendations?

Tags: english-to-japanese

So I would like to ask someone some book recommendations.
I've studied 「ほうがいいです。」but I'm not sure if 「何の本を読んだほうがいいですか。」would be OK.

Should I say it in another way?

Comment: I am not sure if you can have a proper conversation about that here. There are some great books introduced by the community [https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese/759#759]. But more than that if you want to go into the details, since everyone has his own opinion and maybe for some other reason, it's maybe the policy of the site not to have a conversation about it. Of course this is my assumption and I could be wrong since I am myself new to the community.

Comment: What I mean is how to ask “which book do you recommend me” in Japanese

Comment: You are right! Just now I realised what you say!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“何の本を読んだ方がいいですか“ is not wrong, but it sounds a bit awkward.

“方がいい” following any verb literally means “had better do something”. So, it’s used when you have multiple things to compare, and the person you are talking to has to know what you are comparing.

If your friend is talking about multiple books, you can ask “どの本を読んだ方がいいと思う？(=which books do you think I’d better read?)”.
何の本 sounds like “what kind of books”, so you’d better say “どの本“ (=“which book”). “いいですか” sounds like you have something to achieve through reading, so it’s more natural to say “思いますか(what do you think)”.

If you want to ask someone about their recommendations without any context like this,
you can say...

> 1. 何か本のおすすめはありますか？
>      Do you have any books you would recommend?
>      (“何か“=“any”)
> 2. おすすめの本はあったりしますか？
>      =not directly, but it means something like
>      “I was wondering if you had any recommendations for reading.”
>      It’s really common to be used as well.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It has been really helpful. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

You can say

> おすすめの本はありますか

Which literally is

> Is there a book you recommend?